# Need an idiot-proof picture resizing program for Windows

Tags: windows, batch, processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Program to automate image resize](https://superuser.com/questions/30801/program-to-automate-image-resize)

My friend needs to resize some pictures as part of a web publishing job, but he is rather clueless when it comes to computers. I am in charge of teaching him how to do this, but only have Linux (albeit with Wine installed) at my disposal for testing. Could you guys recommend a fast, easy, batch-capable, and hopefully open-source program that will resize pictures to the resolution he wants? It doesn't have to be anything fancy, but it needs to be quick and easy to use. Thanks!

Comment: This is an exact dupe. The same answers are being posted.

Comment: The best program could have changed since August of '09. Programs do come and go over time. Close it if you want, though...

Comment: @marcusw: that's why you can still post answers to old questions.  it's also why we have a close reason of *"too localized"*.

Answer (score 5):

[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) is basically an image viewer, but it is capable of simple image manipulation. It also supports batch processing. Not open source, but freeware.

Comment: Our image batching program that we normally use for setting image size crapped out at about 30000 images, we used IrfanView in batch mode to complete the operation on over 50000 images. I wish I could add more than one plus.

Comment: I will recommend this one to him and accept this answer if it works out.

Answer (score 1):

[Picasa](http://www.picasa.com) from Google would work

Answer (score 0):

Should be good with [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) for Windows an this little plugin : http://photocomix-resources.deviantart.com/art/Lost-Found-Gimp-batch-DPB-73910770

Also, maybe it's already include in Gimp right now, been I while since the last time I used it.

Comment: Gimp would theoretically work, but it's complicated and I'd like something intuitive and small.

Answer (score 0):

[Faststone image viewer](http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm) is about the easiest and fastest I've used.

Answer (score 0):

I also like Irfanview and use it a constantly. One that is very similar and would offer the opportunity for you to have the same native app on Linux is XnView http://www.xnview.com/en/xnview.html I have used it on both platforms and is my first recommendation for other people. I just stick with Irfanview because I have used it for years.